# Using local storage in hybrid applications

Tags: local-storage, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am developing a hybrid application where I want to store images, documents and videos in the device. In my windows app I used to store data in the local storage (C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Packages).

How do I proceed in the hybrid app. I will be deploying it in Windows, iOS and Android devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in

```
window.localStorage
```

Here is more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at angular-localforage. [This article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-localforage-offline-data-storage) describes its usage.

It basically makes it easy to store key / value pairs in the local storage.

As this is a JS / Browser based solution it should work for the mentioned OS in your hybrid application.